# Shall i need to change installation type of Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I install Ubuntu 16.04 at one years ago on my laptop.

That time i choose this selection:

> "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager"

Not choosing others tutorial most reccomended way:

Create a partition and then choose this selection:

> "Something else"

So my question are:

Shall i delete my Ubuntu and reinstall it with the tutorial most recommend way (Choosing **Something else**)

And what the pros and cons different them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Something else*" allows you to decide on the partitioning of your disk by yourself. It can be a bit daunting if you do not have experience with partitions and do not know about mount points.

Either way, for an inexperienced user that also uses Windows, the **easiest way** will be to boot into Windows, and use the Windows disk partitioning tools there to remove the current partitions of the previous install. This frees that part of the drive. Benefit of doing it from Windows: you will not be allowed to delete the windows system partition by mistake.

Subsequently, you can run the Ubuntu installer in one of the "easy", automated ways. In your case, selecting to install alongside of Windows. Then, the installer will automatically use the free space and partition and format it for the new installation.

Someone who is more experienced can select "Something Else", and then decide on the partitioning and mount points for the new installation. There is no need for this if all you wish is to have an Ubuntu install along with an existing Windows install.

Comment: Can i see the  the partition by the installer on **Disk Management** in Windows?

Comment: Likely that is the tool, but I didn't use windows anymore for about 10 years.